# Merge multiple nodes with nested nodes

Tags: xslt

I am newbie in XSL ,but i need XSL file that merge nodes with the same name attribute into one element-and the same done for the son nodes-, and if there is nodes' with different names it put as it , a example of XML is as follows .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <component name="root">
        <component name="c2">
            <component name="c3">
                <component name="c4" />
            </component>
        </component>
    </component>
    <component name="root">
        <component name="c2">
            <component name="A4" />
        </component>
        <component name="root">
            <component name="A3" />
        </component>
        <component name="root">
            <component name="X1">
                <component name="X2" />
            </component>
        </component>
    </component>
    <component name="difRoot">
    </component>
</test>
```

The desired output is as follows

```
<output>
<component name="root">
    <component name="c2">
        <component name="c3">
            <component name="c4"/>
        </component>
        <component name="A4"/>
    </component>
    <component name="A3"/>
          <component name="X1">
                 <component name="X2"/>
          </component>
</component>
<component name="difRoot"/>
</output>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kComponentByName" match="component" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <output>
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="pSequence" select="*"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="merge">
        <xsl:param name="pSequence" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:if test="$pSequence">
            <xsl:variable name="vName" select="$pSequence[1]/@name"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$pSequence[1]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                             select="key('kComponentByName',$vName)
                                        /component[@name != $vName]"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:call-template name="merge">
                <xsl:with-param name="pSequence"
                     select="$pSequence[@name != $vName]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<output>
    <component name="root">
        <component name="c2">
            <component name="c3">
                <component name="c4" />
            </component>
            <component name="A4" />
        </component>
        <component name="A3" />
        <component name="X1">
            <component name="X2" />
        </component>
    </component>
    <component name="difRoot" />
</output>
```

**Note**: Recursive hierarchy is not fully addressed, only prevents myself as child.

**Update**: Named template explanation: if `pSequence` isn't empty, take the first node then copy itself and apply templates to children of all the `component` elements with the same `@name` (filtering those with this `@name` also); lastly call itself filtering `pSequence` of the `component` elements with the same `@name` as the processed one. So, it goes level by level and node by node filtering siblings and children. Full circularity preventions should be do it passing a sequence with ancestors names in order to filter. That's left as exercise...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Alejandro , u made my day :D

Comment: @Alejandro: could you please add a couple of sentences explaining how your stylesheet works? I was interested in this question, but I was able to find an answer. I've read your code, but I think I don't quite understand how it works.